# Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            alert('Window loaded');
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('DOM Loaded and ready');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its so simple, yet I am getting the error

```
 "Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'".
```

I am using Internet Explorer

What is the reason for it?

Comment: What version of IE do you use, since IE<9 doesn't support indexOf. try `inArray`

Comment: use jquery versions 1.x for older versions of ie

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `load` function has been deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 3.0. Use the `on` method instead

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(window).on("load",function () {
            alert('Window loaded');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

From https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/

> Removed deprecated event aliases
>
> .load, .unload, and .error, deprecated since jQuery 1.8, are no more. Use .on() to register listeners.

Comment: I am not getting the error now. You are right that the load method is deprecated. 
A new question arises though that now window.on method fires before document.ready.
It is said that window.ready fires before window.load because window.load waits for all the images etc load, while the document.ready function fires immediately when the DOM is ready.
But now this does not hold true.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```js
   $(window).load(function () {
            alert('Window loaded');
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('DOM Loaded and ready');
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```